Loading.tsx not working when using <Link> to its own page in Nextjs14
I am using nextjs 14.2.7, the root page is a server component that get a ticket from a server action
import { random } from "lodash";
import Link from "next/link";

const getTicket = () => new Promise<number>((r) => {
  const ret = random(1, 10000);
  setTimeout(() => r(ret), 2000)
})
export default async function Home() {

  const newTicket = await getTicket(); // Get a new ticket from server action

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Your new ticket is: {newTicket}</h1>
      <Link href={`/?q=${newTicket}`}>Get a new ticket</Link>
    </>
  );
}

This is loading page
export default async function Loading() {
    return (
        <h1 className="loader">
            LOADING...
        </h1>
    )
}

The loading page can display when clicking refresh button in the browser. But not working when clicking the link 'Get a new ticket', the page is blocked for 2 seconds until the new ticket generated.
Did I misunderstand the usage of loading page? Are there any special configurations or coding considerations for this case? Thanks!

Just now I realized you acctually said it IS an server components so my first answer is completely irreverent, provided one for server components.

Your Loading component won't load automatically, you can use Suspense and pass it as fallback so that it displays until newTicket resolves.
import { random } from "lodash";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Loading } from "<proper path>";
import { Suspense } from "react";

const getTicket = () => new Promise<number>((r) => {
  const ret = random(1, 10000);
  setTimeout(() => r(ret), 2000)
})
export default async function Home() {

  const newTicket = await getTicket(); // Get a new ticket from server action

  return (
    <>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <h1>Your new ticket is: {newTicket}</h1>
      <Link href={`/?q=${newTicket}`}>Get a new ticket</Link>
    </>
  );
}


thanks for your reply, this seems to be a  bug in nextjs side :(
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49297
And your solution is almost the same as community provided, but just add a key in Suspense
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49297#issuecomment-1568557317
Thank you!
